# flask automatic redirects when I start the server

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a bare-minimum getting started with flask code. When I run server my terminal gets flooaded with 405 URL call(I am not making API calls explicitly from anywhere) No idea why it's doing that.

views.py

```
from app import app
from flask import jsonify


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Hello, World!'})
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

import views, models, resources

api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration, '/registration')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogin, '/login')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogoutAccess, '/logout/access')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogoutRefresh, '/logout/refresh')
api.add_resource(resources.TokenRefresh, '/token/refresh')
api.add_resource(resources.AllUsers, '/users')
api.add_resource(resources.SecretResource, '/secret')
```

[SS of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFhXo.png)

Comment: POST requests are not allowed by default. Add the `methods` argument to `route` for allowing POST requests.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant. Whenever I start the flask server, it automatically sends that request, I don't know from where but it constantly gets called when I am not even calling it..

Comment: Do you have a web page that expects to be able to post to your api open in a browser?

Comment: No I don't, that is why it is so weird, I don't have a webpage that makes POST request to my route. I have no idea where it's coming from, and my terminal is just getting floaded with 405 request.. which makes my dev much more painful